# Is the space in a blank tag (<county />) required?

Tags: xml, soap

I'm debugging some XML, and the XML contains a snippet of an address:

```
<address>
    <streetAddress>123 Fake Street</streetAddress>
    <streetAddress2/>
    <city>Schenectady</city>
    <county/>
    <stateCode>NY</stateCode>
    <zip>12345</zip>
    <countryCode>USA</countryCode>
</address>
```

The county and streetAddress2 lines both have blank tags, but are missing the space between the forward slash and the tag name. Could this cause the XML to fail with the parser, or is this space irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the space is irrelevant.